# How to give page curl animation in webView?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiwebview, pdf-reader

I am working on PDF Reader application. if i display pdf file then i am not able to change font size of this.

So i display ePub file in UIWebView. But my problem is how to add page curl animation in UIWebView like iBook and kindle apps does.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867060/uiwebview-and-animation  May be it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a UIWebView named myWebView and on clicking the button the curl effect will be shown on the webview:-

```
    -(IBAction) nextPageAnimationForWebView{        
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setDuration:1.0f];
    animation.startProgress = 0.5;
    animation.endProgress   = 1;
    [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [animation setType:@"pageCurl"];

        //[animation setType:kcat]; 
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionMoveIn];

    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [animation setFillMode: @"extended"];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
    [[myWebView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"WebPageCurl"]; 

}
```

Please tell if this solved your answer.

Comment: it's code is working but i want to use PDF Reader like iBook & kindle Application.

Comment: Please explain your problem in detail

Comment: I am working on PDF Reader application. If i use the UIView and draw the PDF content on this then i will be able to create animation on UIView.


But in this i am not able to highlight Search text & change font size for PDF. And when i use ePub and display in web view then i will be able to highlight search text and change font size.

But i dont know how to animate web view like page curl animation to change page.

Comment: Thank you Anil this really helps .except that I need flipping direction to be toggle-able left to right/right to left. can I change the direction of flipping? thank you.