# OpenGL/CoreGraphics to page curl layer (not animation)

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, uiview, core-graphics

I am attempting to take a CALayer and put a small page curl at the bottom right. Similar to how the iOS Maps on iPad looks.

I think how they do it is by starting a page curl and stopping it at something like 0.004, so all you see is the corner pulled up. Then when you tap it, it completes the animation sequence.

I am doing this on iOS 5 and can't seem to get this to work and I am not sure if this implementation is acceptable by Apple.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

This is beginning and end position of the animation sequence.

Comment: How to go about this exactly. Do you use OpenGL, start a page curl animation and stop it part way?? I can't find anything that works.

Comment: A quick Google search turns up [this method](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/). According to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681315/partial-page-curl-animation), you can now use the page curl transition in your code and it won't be rejected from the app store. [Here's another suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178378/how-to-give-page-curl-animation-in-webview).