# Page Curl on UIScrollView inside the UIWebview

Tags: ios, xcode, ibooks, page-curl

I was amazed by the iBook PageCurl, and I thought I could add this feature to my books application, so here is information about how my project is built, 
project is divided into a two levels, top layer is the UIWebview that loads a local web content for each page, inside the UIwebview there is the built-in UIScrollview that behaves like a normal scrollview with paging feature on, and loading new page according to the rotation left or right side by catching delegate scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:

Im woundering how could I add the PageCurl Animation to the build-in scrollview, or how can I change the code to support pageCurl animation, I found a lot of open source projects on the internet that demonstrates the PageCurl feature buy the issue that its all uses PageViewController which means if I should use this means allocating view controllers with webview inside that means a lot of memory usage and less user experience quality.

im woundering how could I change the UIScrollView Paging into PageCurl feature.

here is the allocation code of the webview and the scrollview inside

```
webContent_ = [[UIWebViewEx alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
[webContent_ setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[webContent_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[webContent_ setDelegate:self];
[webContent_ setContextMenuDelegate:self];
[webContent_ setMarkupDelegate:self];
[webContent_ setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeNone];
[webContent_ setClipsToBounds:NO];
[self addSubview:webContent_];

webScroller_ = [webContent_.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[webScroller_ setPagingEnabled:YES];
[webScroller_ setBounces:NO];
[webScroller_ setDelegate:self];
[webScroller_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[webScroller_ setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[webScroller_ setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[webScroller_ setClipsToBounds:NO];
```

thanks for the help

Comment: take  a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178378/how-to-give-page-curl-animation-in-webview

Comment: and maybe http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/83378-page-curl-uiwebview.html

Comment: this is the github link she's talking bout in the second link https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader/issues/5

Comment: sorry i dont want an animation i want to scroll the page like pagecurl, not animate the paging, i want the user move page like he is reading a book like iBook

Comment: user784625 hi i also want to implement page curl animation. have u get any solution. Thanx in advance